# Changing background colour of table with JavaScript.but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the colour of the table cells background with a function. The code is simple but somehow it isn't working. Can you help

```js
function changecolor() {
      
    var t = document.getElementById("t1");
    var cells = t.getElementsByTagName("td");
    /*Now cells become array-like, with td tag elements 
    indexed*/

    cells[0] = style.backgroundColor = "red";
   /* I suspect the code above has the error because my js 
   seem to break here.*/
      
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="t1">
    
  <tr>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>surname</th>
     <th>age</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>Ray</td>
     <td>Nkiwane</td>
     <td>26</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>Eric</td>
     <td>cartman</td>
     <td>10</td>
  </tr>
    
</table>
    
<button id="b1" onClick="changecolor()">
  Change to red
</button>
```

When i place an alert inside the function it displays when I click the button, confirming that the button and function are linked properly.but if this alert is at the end of the function, it doesn't display, suggesting that a code inside has an error

Comment: Are you trying to change all of the cells or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
cells[0] = style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

That means you're trying to assign an object named **style** to the element at **cells[0]**.
If you want to change the style property of a specific element you need to do it like this:

```
cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: it was right under my nose all along!. the 2 hours of my life wasted will never be recovered

Comment: Hehe, don't see it as wasted time. I know though sometimes it's the little things causing extreme headaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function changecolor() {

    var t = document.getElementById("t1");
    var cells = t.getElementsByTagName("td");
    /*Now cells become array-like, with td tag elements 
    indexed*/

    cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";


}
```

Change line cells[0] = style.backgroundColor = "red"; to cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";

Comment: just 1, its fixed now. i had used a = instead of a .